# How to generalize a property pattern

Tags: c#

I have classes that has multiple properties which have well-defined name and function but have the same implementation. For example:

```
class Stats
{
    private int attack;
    public int Attack
    {
        get =>
            HasBuff ? attack + 1 : attack;
        set
        {
            if (value < 1 || value > 10)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid value");
            attack = value;
        }
    }

    public int Defense {...}
    public int Speed {...}
}
```

Where `Defense` and `Speed` are to be implemented just like `Attack` . How can I generalize this structure to avoid redundancy and make changes easier?

Comment: Can you give an example? How would an interface help me reorganize this code?

Comment: do you want to generalize the validation and "has buff rule" ?

Comment: Well, you could implement a `PropertyBag<int>`, but unless you have a _lot_ of properties, it would be more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make another class to generalize stats:

```
public class Stat
{
    public bool HasBuff { get; set; }

    private int _stat;
    public int Score
    {
        get => HasBuff ? _stat + 1 : _stat;
        set => _stat = value;
    }
}
```

Then just use that for each of your skills:

```
public class CombatStats
{
   public Stat Attack { get; } = new Stat();
   public Stat Defense { get; } = new Stat();
   public Stat Speed { get; } = new Stat();
}
```

Calling code would look like this:

```
var ninja = new Ninja();
ninja.skills = new CombatStats();
var attackStrength = ninja.skills.Attack.Score;
```

As further improvement, implicit operators can be used to avoid object creation and call to Score:

```
public class Stat
{
    ...

    public static implicit operator int(Stat stat)
    {
        return stat.Score;
    }

    public static implicit operator Stat(int value)
    {
        return new Stat()
        {
            Score = value
        };
    }
}
```

This makes the change transparent to client code written w.r.t. to the example in the question:

```
ninja.skills = new CombatStats(){
    Attack = 5,
    Defense = 2
}
int attack = ninja.skills.Attack;
```

Comment: In this case the `Stat` properties should probably be read only,

Comment: @rzippo Somebody rejected your `implicit` edit, but I like it, I think my subsequent approval will retain your changes.

Comment: @McGuireV10 Yes it appears as accepted now, thank you

Answer (score 3):

One approach to consider:

```
class Stats
{
    // other existing code here

    private int defense;

    public int Defense
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(defense);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(value, ref defense);
        }
    }

    private int GetValue(int value)
    {
        return HasBuff ? value + 1 : value;
    }

    private void SetValue(int value, ref int target)
    {
        if (value < 1 || value > 10)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid value");
        target = value;
    }
}
```

*`Attack` etc will now be basically the same as `Defence` but passing in `attack` rather than `defense` to `GetValue` and `SetValue`.*

Answer (score 2):

I would go with composition

Stat:

```
    public class Stats
    {
        private readonly StatProperty _defense;
        private readonly StatProperty _attack;
        private readonly StatProperty _speed;

        public Stats()
        {
            _defense = new StatProperty(this);
            _attack = new StatProperty(this);
            _speed = new StatProperty(this);
        }

        public int Defense
        {
            get => _defense.Value;
            set => _defense.Value = value;
        }

        public int Attack
        {
            get => _attack.Value;
            set => _attack.Value = value;
        }
        public int Speed
        {
            get => _speed.Value;
            set => _speed.Value = value;
        }

        public bool HasBuff { get; set; }

    }
```

StatProperty:

```
    public class StatProperty
    {
        public Stats Stats { get; }

        public StatProperty(Stats stats)
        {
            Stats = stats;
        }

        private int _value = 1;
        public int Value
        {
            get => Stats.HasBuff ? _value + 1 : _value;
            set
            {
                if (value < 1 || value > 10)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid value");
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would need more details to know if it is the best option.

you also could make StatProperty as internal if don't want to show it outside of your library or nested private class if you want to use this just on the class Stats

Comment: This looks very similar to the accepted answer, but with much more code in the Stats class